# PrimeFaces/JSF component ID not found from within p:datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm just starting with PrimeFaces 3.3.1 coming off RichFaces 3 and 4.

I have a datatable with the structure:

```
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Employees" />
            </f:facet>

            <p:column sortBy="#{emp.lastName}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Last Name" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{emp.lastName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="First Name" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{emp.firstName}" />
            </p:column>

            ...

            <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"
                                     value="Remove"
                                     process="@this"
                                     update="employee-remove-dialog"
                                     oncomplete="employeeRemoveDialog.show();">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{employeeManager.currentEmployee}" value="#{emp}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:dialog header="Remove Employee"
                  modal="true"
                  appendToBody="true"
                  widgetVar="employeeRemoveDialog"
                  id="employee-remove-dialog">
            <h:outputText value="Remove employee #{employeeManager.currentEmployee.fullName}?" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-check"
                                 value="OK"
                                 action="#{employeeManager.deleteEmployee}"
                                 process="@this"
                                 update="employee-list"
                                 oncomplete="employeeRemoveDialog.hide();" />
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-close"
                                 value="Cancel"
                                 onclick="employeeRemoveDialog.hide();"
                                 ajax="false"
                                 immediate="true" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
```

However PrimeFaces throws an exception:

```
09:36:08,961 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Rendering View[/employeeList.xhtml]: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "employee-remove-dialog" referenced from "j_idt30:employee-list:0:j_idt41".
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findClientIds(ComponentUtils.java:251) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addIds(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:102) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:90) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:195) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:74) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:49) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularCell(DataTableRenderer.java:780) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:741) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:645) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:248) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:220) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:107) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:55) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
```

The ID cannot be found. Hmm.... I basically copied the structure from RichFaces. There the row button to delete or edit the row doesn't need the :employee-form:... prefixing. **I wonder why.**

When giving the form an ID and prefixing the PF component references with the ':' syntax the code runs as expected:

```
    <h:form id="employee-form">
        <p:dataTable ...>
            ...
            <p:column>
                <h:panelGrid ...>
                    <p:commandButton ...
                                     update=":employee-form:employee-remove-dialog"
                                     ...>
                        ...
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:dialog ...
                  id="employee-remove-dialog">
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

**Q:**

Why does a p:datatable need to prefix the root JSF IDs? Maybe it's my code, but the example posted seems minimal to me. In any case, using this will result in possibly long IDs all over the application.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm on JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final, Mojarra 2.1.7, PF 3.3.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PrimeFaces uses the standard JSF algorithm as provided by [`UIComponent#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) to find components by a given client ID. The algorithm is in detail described in the aforelinked javadoc. Here's an extract of relevance:

> A *search expression* consists of either an identifier (which is matched exactly against the id property of a `UIComponent`, or a series of such identifiers linked by the `UINamingContainer#getSeparatorChar` character value. The search algorithm should operates as follows, though alternate alogrithms may be used as long as the end result is the same:
>
> - Identify the `UIComponent` that will be the base for searching, by stopping as soon as one of the following conditions is met:
>
>   - If the search expression begins with the the separator character (called an "absolute" search expression), the base will be the root `UIComponent` of the component tree. The leading separator character will be stripped off, and the remainder of the search expression will be treated as a "relative" search expression as described below.
>   - Otherwise, if this `UIComponent` is a `NamingContainer` it will serve as the basis.
>   - Otherwise, search up the parents of this component. If a `NamingContainer` is encountered, it will be the base.
>   - Otherwise (if no `NamingContainer` is encountered) the root `UIComponent` will be the base.
> - The search expression (possibly modified in the previous step) is now a "relative" search expression that will be used to locate the component (if any) that has an id that matches, within the scope of the base component. The match is performed as follows:
>
>   - If the search expression is a simple identifier, this value is compared to the id property, and then recursively through the facets and children of the base `UIComponent` (except that if a descendant `NamingContainer` is found, its own facets and children are not searched).
>   - If the search expression includes more than one identifier separated by the separator character, the first identifier is used to locate a `NamingContainer` by the rules in the previous bullet point. Then, the `findComponent()` method of this `NamingContainer` will be called, passing the remainder of the search expression.

RichFaces uses the same algorithm ["with some additional exceptions"](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#Re-Rendering).

> *"reRender"* uses `UIComponent.findComponent()` algorithm (with some additional exceptions) to find the component in the component tree.

Those additional exceptions are nowhere in detail described, but it's well known that relative component IDs (i.e. those not starting with `:`) are not only searched in the context of the closest parent `NamingContainer`, but also in all other `NamingContainer` components in the same view (which is a relatively expensive job by the way).

Comment: (+1) Thanks for posting the algorithm: That is much more help full than an concrete for an concrete case.